# How to create an reverse proxy behind an CDN (another reverse proxy)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cdn, cloudflare

I have the www.site.com and I have the blog.site.com.

On site.com server I have a nginx reverse proxy pointing from www.site.com/blog to www.blog.com and everything works fine, here's the code:

```
location  /blog {
  proxy_read_timeout 30s;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass       http://blog.site.com;
  proxy_redirect   off;
}
```

But when I add the CloudFlare CDN i got the error 1000 because it's another reverse proxy. (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171976-Error-1000-DNS-points-to-prohibited-IP)

How can I solve that?

Comment: Have you found a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because cloudflare detected that the site at `blog.site.com` is hosted at cloudflare too and there is a chance that allowing you to do this will create a request loop.

Possible solutions:

1. Take one of the hosts off cloudflare;
2. Proxy directly to the IP address of the host inside nginx.

Code:

```
location  /blog {
  proxy_read_timeout 30s;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass       http://{Your-Host-IP-Address};
  proxy_redirect   off;
}
```